# Red Pitaya freezes after changing ADC clock to external

Tags: redpitaya

I use the Red Pitaya STEM 125-14. Recently, I change the RedPitaya ADC clock to external clock from FPGA, by moving R25 and R26 to R27 and R28.

But, when I turn on the RedPitaya again, I think the CPU is hang (Red and Orange LED is not blinking). I see in UART console, the boot process stops at this line: "Starting Registering Red Pitaya boa...ss and IP address to a server..." This is the complete [boot log](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1q6SjRbxPz5sy8ErWd42pS1hdMWNcxpEj/view).

I have replace the SD card with another RedPitaya's SD card, but the problem still exists. I have modified the ADC clock source in red_pitaya_top.sv to the external clock, then replace the bitstream file, but the problem still exists.

Does anyone have any idea why this might be happening? (is it because of the RedPitaya ADC clock?)
How to get the RedPitaya work after chaging the ADC clock to the external clock?

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem by re-installing the OS with the latest version 0.98 build 617 (redpitaya_ubuntu_17-11-35_01-sep-2017).